# ComboBox SelectedItem property won't change

Tags: c#, combobox

Hi I've got a problem with a comboBox.
At the beginning the `documentTypeComboBox.SelectedItem` value is null, then the `GetDataRow()` method return DataRow which is not null (100% sure that it return not null value for my test)
After all the value of the SelectedItem property is still null. No idea what is wrong. I'm 100% sure that the returned DataRow is assigned as comboBox DataSource row

```
    public void SetDefaultData()
    {
        documentTypeComboBox.SelectedItem = null;

        dataWystawieniaDate.Value = _Faktura.DataWystawienia;
        dataSprzedazyDate.Value = _Faktura.DataSprzedazy;

        warehouseComboBox.SelectedItem = Helpers.GetDataRow(_Dictionary.Magazines, _Faktura.Magnum);
        paymentMethodComboBox.SelectedItem = Helpers.GetDataRow(_Dictionary.SpPaymentMethodsData, _Faktura.IdSposobuPlatnosci);
        priceComboBox.SelectedItem = Helpers.GetDataRow(_Dictionary.PricesData, _Faktura.RodzajCeny);
        discountComboBox.SelectedItem = Helpers.GetDataRow(_Dictionary.RabatyData, _Faktura.RodzajRabatu);
        documentTypeComboBox.SelectedItem = Helpers.GetDataRow(_Dictionary.SpDocumentsCodes, _Faktura.Kod, documentTypeComboBox.DisplayMember);

        documentNumberTextBox.Text = _Faktura.Numer;
        kwotaBruttoTextBox.Text = _Faktura.PlnWartoscBrutto.ToString();
    }


    public static DataRow GetDataRow(DataTable dt, string value, string fieldName)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dr[fieldName].ToString() == value)
                return dr;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set the DataSource ?

Comment: `private void LoadData()
        {

            documentTypeComboBox.DataSource = _Dictionary.SpDocumentsCodes;
            documentTypeComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
            documentTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "KOD";
 }`

Comment: Are you trying to set DataRow objects in the combo? Is this WPF?

Comment: No DataSource is DataTable selected from SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i figure it out. SelectedItem property is DataRowView not DataRow. This explains why it doesn't select the correct value. 
Use SelectedValue instead :)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/77b23eb9-112f-4fea-9d3a-486b822f22ea/combobox-datatable-selecteditem

Comment: Okay, I'll check this, but look upper, `discountComboBox` using same method and it's working `public static DataRow GetDataRow(DataTable dt, int id)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]) == id)
                    return dr;
            }
            return null;
        }`

Comment: Maybe it's always set the 1st item in the combo...I doubt it works in other cases

Comment: It's working thanks, but why it won't work just with 1 combo, when i have 5 all working same way.

Comment: Good. Happy it works. As I said before maybe is always selected the 1st item in the comboboxes and you can't really see that if you would change to anything else than 1st item, it wouldn't work.